# Battlefield 1: Transfer License from PS4 to XBOX ONE

Tags: ps4, xbox-one, battlefield-1, legal

I've bought Battlefield 1 downloading it from the Playstation Store, but I will need to have it on my XBOX One, without using it anymore on the PS4.

Is it possible to transfer the license (by means of Origin/EA support) or shall I have to buy another Battefield 1 License?

Comment: No this isn't possible. You'll need to buy the game again.

Comment: Ok thanks. Don't know why the negativity, though

Comment: Mostly because this should be obvious. What makes you think this would be at all possible?

Comment: @Frank: why so obvious? I have a digital copy of BF1. Why transferring the right to use it from a platform to another should be aprioristically forbidden? Other softwares (on PCs) allow transferring license to another platform (Mac to Linux for example) without buying the same thing again, why for games it should be obvious it cannot be done? Anyways, nevermind, thanks everyone for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot transfer your PS4 games to XBox One. They are completely different consoles and games on both consoles are not compatible even if they are digital.

Comment: No no, not the games, just the license... the XB1 game would be downloaded from the marketplace, just in case

Comment: That doesn't make any difference XBox One and PS4 licences are not the same thing and will not transfer.

Comment: Ok, thank you. As a side note, it seems everyone is taking it personal, I do not want to steal games/license I just want to know if it is foreseen to transfer the license, that's all. If not, I'll simply buy the game again.

Comment: @BerserkEVA I am sure the downvotes are just due to lack of research on the question. It's not anything to take personally. There were no mentions of stealing or anything it's just the question causing the downvotes.

Comment: Ok thank you. I've tried to contact Origin to require assistance about it but it seems less easy than expected. By the way, ok.